# Make a value static and share it with FB.UI

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook SDK to add a share button in my document. The problem is, I want the quote of my share button to be a word from the array that i've created. Let me explain better:

What do I have: A file to shuffle a word from an array using the function printword. I printed the word inside i div with the ID result. Now, how can I get the shuffled word that the user got and use it as a facebook share's quote/message body?

Comment: You are not allowed to pre-fill the message part of any post or share, it has to be typed in by the user.

Comment: Wow, then what is the Quote?

Comment: The Open Graph title and/or description of the link you let the user share.